# Can't Update Rest-Client Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundler, rest-client

bundle-audit reports:

```
Name: rest-client
Version: 1.6.8
Advisory: CVE-2015-1820
Criticality: Unknown
URL: https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/369
Title: rubygem-rest-client: session fixation vulnerability via Set-Cookie headers in 30x redirection responses
Solution: upgrade to >= 1.8.0
```

But when I try to update to 1.8.0, I find there are all kinds of dependencies that can't go to 1.8.0

What am I missing? My Google-foo got me nowhere.

Additional context:

In a moment of security-mindedness, I installed bundle-audit this AM and ran it against the only app I have in prod. It's not used by anyone but my wife, but I would like it secure (the vulnerability in my case would probably require a login, which is unlikely, but still). bundle-audit reported two vulnerabilities with rest-client, and suggests upgrading to 1.8.0.  Bundle update keeps pulling in version 1.6.8. I have reviewed my Gemfile, and there doesn't appear to be any explicit version requirement for any of the gems that pull in rest-client. (There is no reference to rest-client at all in the Gemfile.) gem dependency rest-client 1.6.8 shows webmock and mime-types as dependent:

```
gem rest-client-1.6.8
  mime-types (~> 1.16)
  pry (>= 0, development)
  rake (~> 10.0, development)
  rdoc (>= 2.4.2)
  rspec (~> 2.4, development)
  webmock (~> 1.4, development)

Gem rest-client-1.8.0
  http-cookie (< 2.0, >= 1.0.2)
  mime-types (< 3.0, >= 1.16)
  netrc (~> 0.7)
  pry (>= 0, development)
  pry-doc (>= 0, development)
  rdoc (< 5.0, >= 2.4.2, development)
  rspec (~> 2.4, development)
  webmock (~> 1.4, development)
```

When I attempt to remove rest-client 1.68, gem complains differently though:

```
ast-2.1.0 depends on rest-client (~> 1.6.7, development)
heroku-3.42.36 depends on rest-client (= 1.6.8)
heroku-3.42.33 depends on rest-client (= 1.6.8)
heroku-3.42.21 depends on rest-client (= 1.6.8)
heroku-3.8.4 depends on rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
heroku-3.8.3 depends on rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
heroku-3.8.2 depends on rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
heroku-3.8.1 depends on rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
heroku-3.6.0 depends on rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
heroku-3.3.0 depends on rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
heroku-3.2.3 depends on rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
heroku-3.0.1 depends on rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
parser-2.2.3.0 depends on rest-client (~> 1.6.7, development)
parser-2.2.2.6 depends on rest-client (~> 1.6.7, development)
parser-2.2.0.3 depends on rest-client (~> 1.6.7, development)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
```

When I remove it, it just gets pulled in again.

BTW, why does the removal cause additional dependencies beyond those reported by 'gem dependency' to popup?  (Are they indirect?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know you posted this a year ago, but I was having the same issue so I came across it. With me the issue was that in my Gemfile I had:

```
gem "rest-client", "1.6.7"
```

I just removed the version:

```
gem "rest-client"
```

and then ran `bundle update rest-client`

Comment: Thanks A. Saloff.  I don't know what I did, but your comment is worthwhile.